# Regression loop in R for data frames

Tags: r, loops, statistics, dataframe, regression

```
rm(list=ls())
myData <-read.csv(file="C:/Users/Documents/myfile.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",") 
for(i in names(myData))
{
    colNum <- grep(i,colnames(myData)) ##asigns a value to each column 
    if(is.numeric(myData[3,colNum]))  ##if row 3 is numeric, the entire column is 
   {
        ##print(nxeData[,i])        
        fit <- lm(myData[,i] ~ etch_source_Avg, data=myData) #does a regression for each column in my csv file against my independent variable 'etch'
        rsq <- summary(fit)$r.squared   
   }
}
```

> I'm working on doing a regression loop for multiple columns and comparing them against one dependent variable column. I have the majority of the code written, but now I am unsure how to print out my R squared value for each column against the etch_source_Avg parameter while including the name of that column. Ideally it would something look like:
>
> .765   "variable name 1"
>
> .436   "variable name 2" ...and so on

Comment: Hi Jacob: Normally I would never do this, but I have an already-written answer to your just-deleted question about performing regressions on subsets of data that may be helpful for you, and I wanted to make sure it reached you just in case it was helpful. [Here](http://pastebin.com/HPjJ9Wzz)'s the code for my answer. I'd also be happy to post it if you undeleted your question, or to stop bothering you if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thank you for the help!! I didn't want to break any of the forum rules so I took it down. Feel free to post it to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623230/regression-of-a-data-frame-with-multiple-factor-groupings) and I would be happy to select it as the best answer. You are not bothering me at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a quick rewrite of your code, this should give you what you are looking for. Assigning a value of each column is unnecessary since `myData` should be a data.frame, as such you can access each column with it's column name.

```
rm(list=ls())
myData <-read.csv(file="C:/Users/Documents/myfile.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",") 
for(i in names(myData))
{ 
    if(is.numeric(myData[3,i]))  ##if row 3 is numeric, the entire column is 
    {       
       fit <- lm(myData[,i] ~ etch_source_Avg, data=myData) #does a regression for each column in my csv file against my independent variable 'etch'
       rsq <- summary(fit)$r.squared
       writelines(paste(rsq,i,"\n"))
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.